# How to remove a selected Chip outside of Autocomplete in material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, multi-select

So I want to display selected values as `<Chip />` outside of the `<TextField />` in `<Autocomplete />`. I was able to display values as `state`. However, I still have trouble deleting those chips, i.e. not just the display, but also change the `selected` prop in `<Autocomplete />`. Does anyone have an idea?

```
  const [val, setVal] = useState([]);

  const valHtml = val.map((option, index) => (
    <Chip
      label={option.title}
      deleteIcon={<RemoveIcon />}
      onDelete={() => {}}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        filterSelectedOptions
        options={top100Films}
        onChange={(e, newValue) => setVal(newValue)}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
        renderTags={() => {}}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="standard"
            placeholder="Favorites"
            margin="normal"
            fullWidth
          />
        )}
      />
      <div className="selectedTags">{valHtml}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Complete code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-wllfw)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need two things:

1. Appropriate logic in the `onDelete` of the `Chip` such as:

```
      onDelete={() => {
        setVal(val.filter(entry => entry !== option));
      }}
```

2. Specify the value (which you are already managing in state) on the `Autocomplete`:

```
      <Autocomplete
        value={val}
        // ... other properties
      />
```

Here is a working version of your sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-with-chips-85rqq

Comment: Thanks for answer. But that only solves half of the problem. The tricky part is to toggle the ‘select’ prop in Autocomplete for the element to delete. The Autocomplete internal API uses ‘select’ for each element from the dataSource/option, but that only stays at the scope of the component, and API very confusing to me.

Comment: @user2683470 I've updated the answer to solve the other half of the problem by specifying the `value` prop.